# How can I copy attribute values from a number of elements and copy each to a different element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a number of elements of tag `<a class="banner2">` each of whom have a different `background image` url and `href` value.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner2" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/koniaris.jpg');">

</a>
```

I also have a same amount of different elements `<a class="banner3">` which I want to have the same background image and href value respectively.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner3">

</a>
```

What I mean is that for each of the `.banner2` elements I want a respective `.banner3` element to have its background image url and href value.

So how do I loop for both classes and copy the attribute values?

Comment: Would it not be simplest to store ALL the banners in a `php` or `javascript` array? Then  loop through them accordingly?  IE `class="banner<?= $key ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this, the CSS sizes are simply so that the elements appear during testing and the red-border is simply to identify which is which.

Capture a reference to all elements of class `banner3` that are to have their background set and also capture a nodelist of all the elements from which to select the background image. Iterate through the nodelist and select the corresponding other node based upon the index `i` - assign the background.

This shows just the background image being copied - as the href attributes are the same there didn't seem much point copying that attribute but it would be a trivial task to do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Copy background image to corresponding element</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                let col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a.banner3') );
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a.banner2') ).forEach( ( a, i )=>{
                    col[ i ].style.backgroundImage=a.style.backgroundImage;
                })
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .banner2, .banner3{ display:block; width:300px; height:300px; margin:1rem; }
            .banner3{ border:1px solid red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner2" style="background-image:url('images/25398691_10214872887759191_3871602197915899055_n.jpg');"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner2" style="background-image:url('images/27972581_10157094423021258_4761504312023581045_n.jpg');"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner2" style="background-image:url('images/183096_1908068104875_1336992821_2226175_4522067_n.jpg');"></a>



        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner3"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner3"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="banner3"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! That easily worked. I was trying to figure it out with j Query but plain JavaScript is fine.

Comment: glad it helped - you could make that more robust by checking lengths of the various nodelists/ arrays etc